# Why does all links of homepage redirects me to Xampp homepage ( Took backup from Godaddy )

Tags: .htaccess

I took backup of SQL from Godaddy and copied all the data from my Godaddy hosting account through FTP. 
I imported the SQL in my machine's mysql ( no issues ). 
I copied the files to my htdocs/subdir1/drupalDIR/ and made changes in settings.php ( updated mysql connection details ).
Homepage is showed in a perfectly fine way but whenever I click on any link, it takes me to Xampp Homepage.

Perhaps it's a htaccess issue.

What should be the Rewrite rule to make it okay ?

Comment: Downloading a fresh copy of Drupal and looking at its .htaccess is the easiest way to see what the rewrite rules should be

Comment: That's what I did, I replaced the one I had with the new one. It works !

Answer (score 0):

I tried copying the .htaccess file available inside the Drupal package and pasted into my htdocs drupal folder.
Works like charm till yet.